# Boot managers found by os-prober not shown at boot

Tags: arch-linux, grub2

I've recently made the move from Ubuntu to Arch Linux and could use some help configuring GRUB.

When I run `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/GRUB/grub.cfg` as per the instructions on [the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB), the following is returned

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-linux
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-linux.img
Found fallback initramfs image: /boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
done
```

A quick look inside `/boot/efi/EFI/GRUB/grub.cfg` has a menuentry from `os-prober` which seems to indicate found my Windows Boot Manager, yet when I reboot and get to the GRUB menu, there is no option for Windows.

How might I go about fixing this?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I set the output parameter of grub-mkconfig to use /boot/grub/grub.cfg and now it's using the correct config, but this feels kind of like a hack. Should the grub configuration not be in the EFI folder?